# GraphQL: Prevent users seeing entries authored by other users

Tags: graphql

How can we filter what entries are returned by a GraphQL query so that users cannot see entries authored by other people?

For example, *Editors* can access everything but *Writers* can only access their own entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using a custom module that adds an `authorId` condition to element queries, for `graphql/api` requests.

```php
use Craft;
use craft\elements\db\EntryQuery;
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;

// ...

// Is this a GraphQL request?
if (Craft::$app->request->getActionSegments() == ['graphql', 'api']) {
    Event::on(EntryQuery::class, EntryQuery::EVENT_BEFORE_PREPARE, function(Event $event) {
        // Get the current user
        $user = Craft::$app->user->identity;

        // If no one is logged in, return a 403 error
        if (!$user) {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException();
        }

        // Only Editors are allowed to see everything
        if (!$user->isInGroup('editors')) {
            /** @var EntryQuery $query */
            $query = $event->sender;
            $query->subQuery->andWhere(['authorId' => $user->id]);
        }
    });
}
```

**Note:** Since the results will start changing for the same element query depending on who is logged in, you’ll also need to disable the [enableGraphQlCaching](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#enablegraphqlcaching) config setting.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct config name for your Craft version:
`enableGraphQlCaching` before Craft CMS 3.7 and `enableGraphqlCaching` after Craft CMS 3.7